# Table splitting – how do we insert a new row?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using table splitting to map entities `Entity1` and `Entity2` to a DB table `MyTable`.

Is there a way to insert a new row into `MyTable` by adding an instance of  `Entity1` (or `Entity2`) to the context and let EF construct the necessary `Insert` command. I tried the following, but it throws an exception:

```
        Entity2 entity = new Entity2();
        context.Entity2.AddObject(entity);

        context.SaveChanges();// UpdateException: Invalid data encountered. A 
                              // required relationship is missing
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must always construct whole record for the split table so if your Entity1 contains navigation property to Entity2 it must be filled:

```
Entity1 entity = new Entity1();
entity.Entity2 = new Entity2();
context.Entity1.AddObject(entity);
context.SaveChanges();
```